# arduino установил tx и rx в режим записи

Tags: arduino

Выставил `DDRD = B11111111;`

Так понимаю, что `tx` и `rx` установились в режим записи,
скетч, записанный последним работает, но теперь не могу прошивать скетчи по `USB`.

Можно это как-то исправить?

`arduino uno r3 ch340` китайская копия.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы прошить микроконтроллер, нужен микроконтроллер...
Бери программатор и прошивай мегу напрямую. Иначе никак.

Answer (score 0):

Используй другой режим аплоадинга-Arduino ISP,к примеру. Если загрузчик на контроллере лежит где надо,при новой загрузке программы ему должно быть не важно,как предыдущая программа работала с твоим UART регистром-порта.